Find arc length inside smaller circle whose center lies on circumference of larger circle
Let $r$ be the radius of a smaller circle whose center lies on the circumference of a larger circle with radius $R$.
Find the arc length $A$ inside the smaller circle that's part of the circumference of the larger circle.
The below diagram shows a smaller circle with radius 10 whose center lies on the circumference of a larger circle with radius 20.
The length to find is outlined in orange and labeled $A$.


On the larger circle, what is the arc length corresponding to a chord of length $r$?

@peterwhy Are you asking if the question is finding the arc length corresponding to a chord length $r$?
In the problem description, $r$ is the radius of the smaller circle.
The chord length would be approximately $2r$, but not exactly $2r$.

The arc $A$ passes through one point of the smaller circle, then the centre of this circle, then another point of this circle. The end points of each half-arc are distance $r$ apart.

Arc $AO_2B =2R\theta$

Applying sine rule in $\triangle O_1AO_2$:
$$\frac{R}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2})}=\frac{r}{\sin \theta}=\frac{R}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2})}$$
\begin{align*}
\implies \frac{R}{r}&=\frac{\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})}{\sin \theta} \\
 2\sin \theta&=\cos(\frac{\theta}{2}) \\
 4\sin (\frac{\theta}{2}) \cos (\frac{\theta}{2})&=\cos(\frac{\theta}{2}) \\
\sin (\frac{\theta}{2}) &=\frac{1}{4} \\
\theta &= 2\sin^{-1} (\frac{1}{4}) 
\end{align*}
so the Arc $AO_2B =2R\theta = 2 \times 20 \times 2\sin^{-1} (\frac{1}{4}) \,$mm = 20.2144 mm

Prince Yadav gave you a geometric/trigonometric derivation; here is a algebraic alternative approach. Without loss of generality, one can rotate the referential, so that the center of the smaller circle lies on the $x$-axis, more precisely at $(R,0)$. Next, let's $(x,y)$ the coordinates of the intersection point in the upper half-plane. Since this point belongs to both circles, its coordinates satisfy the following system :
$$
\begin{cases}
      R^2 =  x^2    + y^2 & (1) \\
   \; r^2 = (x-R)^2 + y^2 & (2)
\end{cases}
$$
The first line leads to $y^2 = R^2 - x^2$, which can be substituted into the second equation, hence
$$
r^2 = (x-R)^2 + (R^2-x^2) = 2R^2 -2Rx
$$
and finally $x = R - \frac{r^2}{2R}$. Now, denoting the angle between the $x$-axis and the intersection point in question as $\theta$, one has $\cos\theta = \frac{x}{R} = 1-\frac{r^2}{2R^2}$ and in the end the desired arclength is given by $\ell = 2R\theta = 2R\arccos\left(1-\frac{r^2}{2R^2}\right)$ by symmetry.

Thanks for providing this approach! I seem to get 26.3623 instead of Yadav's 20.2144 by $2 * 10 * arccos(10/(2*20))$. Did I do something wrong?

@gbroques  I must admit I haven't re-checked either Yadav's answer or mine. Nevertheless, you saw how to proceed, which is what matters.

@Abezhiko you made a little mistake at end. $\cos\theta=x/R \implies \cos\theta=1-\frac{r^2}{2R^2}$ .so $l=2R \cos^{-1} (7/8)$ which will gave exact same result as mine

This thing is also confirmed by Yves Daoust 's approach.

@PrinceYadav  Indeed, you're right. I don't why I tried to compute the the arclength of the smaller circle. It is now corrected.
